# ReferenceError: label is not defined in Dymo framework

Tags: javascript, dymo

I am playing with [Dymo](http://developers.dymo.com/2015/09/24/dymo-label-framework-javascript-library-2-0-open-beta-2/)'s JS framework. The [original example](http://pastebin.com/ivvx6Zdi) works without issue, but it's loading the XML even when I don't want to click. I rewrited to execute Dymo code only when I call it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function printnow() {              
               $.get("./cont.label", function(labelXml) {
               label = dymo.label.framework.openLabelXml(labelXml);
               }, "text");
               // open label
               // set label text
               label.setObjectText("MENO", "test");
               label.setObjectText("MUNKA", "test");
               label.setObjectText("DESCRIPTION", test);
               // select printer to print on
               // for simplicity sake just use the first LabelWriter printer
               var printers = dymo.label.framework.getPrinters();
               if (printers.length == 0) throw "No DYMO printers are installed. Install DYMO printers.";
               var printerName = "";
               for (var i = 0; i < printers.length; ++i) {
                   var printer = printers[i];
                   if (printer.printerType == "LabelWriterPrinter") {
                       printerName = printer.name;
                       break;
                   }
               }
               if (printerName == "") throw "No LabelWriter printers found. Install LabelWriter printer";
               // finally print the label
               label.print(printerName);

       };
</script>
```

Unfortunately after I call printnow(); I get `ReferenceError: label is not defined` Where is the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323?s=1|0.0000#14220323

Comment: That `$.get()` call is **asynchronous**.  The variable `label` won't get a value until the HTTP call completes, but the `$.get()` call itself returns immediately. Put the code that prepares and prints the content **inside** the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to read this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323?s=1%7C0.0000#14220323).

In short, you are dealing with async code. So, this `label.setObjectText("MENO", "test");` and the rest of the code gets executed, before this `label = dymo.label.framework.openLabelXml(labelXml);` line.

Finally, you have to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function printnow() {              
               $.get("./cont.label", function(labelXml) {
               var label = dymo.label.framework.openLabelXml(labelXml);
               // open label
               // set label text
               label.setObjectText("MENO", "test");
               label.setObjectText("MUNKA", "test");
               label.setObjectText("DESCRIPTION", test);
               // select printer to print on
               // for simplicity sake just use the first LabelWriter printer
               var printers = dymo.label.framework.getPrinters();
               if (printers.length == 0) throw "No DYMO printers are installed. Install DYMO printers.";
               var printerName = "";
               for (var i = 0; i < printers.length; ++i) {
                   var printer = printers[i];
                   if (printer.printerType == "LabelWriterPrinter") {
                       printerName = printer.name;
                       break;
                   }
               }
               if (printerName == "") throw "No LabelWriter printers found. Install LabelWriter printer";
               // finally print the label
               label.print(printerName);

               }, "text");

       };
</script>
```